# Memory Access Profiling

Tags: profiling, memory-profiling

I want to know which addresses an application is accessing in the order of access.
I heard that Pin (profiler from Intel) can be used to do this.

Is there any way to do this with Pin or some other tools?

The application is likely to be written in C. I am working on Linux Mint 14.

Note: Visual results would be nice to have but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Pin can do this after all. There is an example tool named 'pinatrace' that traces all the memory access address, whether it is read or write etc. It is not a visual result. It writes all the access information on a text file. It can be a huge file depending on your program's memory footprint and usage.

But it is possible to filter these by changing the injected code in the pin tool's (pinatrace) code, in case you only want to know the access order for a particular array or something (which was my case).

Hope this helps anyone facing similar problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did it for a particular array ?

Comment: It's been a while since I have done it but as far as I remember, I saved the address of the array after allocating it into a global variable and then used that variable and the size of the array to filter memory access inside pin source code. Hopefully this helps.